# Spring Roo not updating JSP views of entities extending abstract entity

Tags: spring-roo

I have an abstract entity. Two other entities, E1 and E2 f.e., extend this entity.
Now I want to add a new field to the abstract entity (focus abstractEntity, field string newField) but then Roo won't update the jsp views of E1 and E2. Only when adding a field directly to E1 or E2.

Is there a way to force the update?

For your information I am using the current 2.0.0 M1 pre-release of Spring Roo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed this issue by adding a field, f.e. "private string newField", to each entity separately (E1, E2). Spring Roo recognizes these changes and generates the corresponding views. When Spring Roo has finished updating the views I add the same field "private string newField" to the abstract base entity and remove it from E1 and E2. 
After rebuilding everything works as expected.